# filtering rows after a groupby and apply a function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm using python and pandas to work on some data.
My data looks like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar'],
                   'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'C' : [True, False, True, True, False, True]})
print(df)

     A  B      C
0  foo  1   True
1  bar  2  False
2  foo  3   True
3  bar  4   True
4  foo  5  False
5  bar  6   True
```

What I would like to do:

1. Groupby by "A"
2. Select the value B by groups where C == True
3. Calculate a mean value on this selection
4. Create a new column "D" to store theses values

So the result would be:

```
    A   B   C       D
0   foo 1   True    2
1   bar 2   False   5
2   foo 3   True    2
3   bar 4   True    5
4   foo 5   False   2
5   bar 6   True    5
```

I have tried some mixes of groupby, filter and transform, but I cannot succed to make it work.
I imagine the solution close to the followings

```
df.groupby(["A"])[df.loc[df["C"] == True, "B"]].transform("mean")
```

or

```
df.groupby(["A"]).filter(lambda x: x["D"] == True)["B"].transform("mean")
```

But none of these syntax work.

Thanks for helping me and people in general,

Comment: In the dataframe definition, it seems you put in 'D' instead of 'C'. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `mean`s of filtered rows, `==True` should be omitted:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].map(df.loc[df.C, 'B'].groupby(df["A"]).mean())
print(df)

     A  B      C  D
0  foo  1   True  2
1  bar  2  False  5
2  foo  3   True  2
3  bar  4   True  5
4  foo  5  False  2
5  bar  6   True  5
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not do what I want. Here your "column" is full of 5 and I expect 2 and 5 depending on the groupby on column "A".

Comment: You will get 2 and 5 is you filter by column "B". From what I can see, filtering with "C" will give you 5 for both groups. Could you explain why you expect 2 and 5?

Comment: My data are measurements. The "A" column correspond to temperature increment. So I want to group by this important caracteristic. Then I want to have a mean value of the column "C" by temperature increment. But I want to make a mean only if "D" is True. "B" is not important for this example.

Comment: @Samovian for `bar` if D is True in C are 1 and 9, mean is (9+1)/2=5. Can you explain why and mainly how get 2?

Comment: @jezrael - Thanks to you !